# a parameter list with an ellipsis can't match an empty parameter name list declaration

Tags: c

Please I don't know why I get "a parameter list with an ellipsis can't match an empty parameter name list declaration" when I run the code below. I believe I did everything right but my gcc compiler is given me that error.

````
#include <stdarg.h>

/**
 * main - check the code
 *
 * Return: Always 0.
 */

int main(void)
{
  int sum;

  sum = sum_them_all(2, 98, 1024);
  printf("%d\n", sum);
  sum = sum_them_all(4, 98, 1024, 402, -1024);
  printf("%d\n", sum);    
  return (0);
}

/**
 * @sum_them_all - calculate the entire sum. 
 * 
 * @n: constant int param signifiying the total num to sum 
 * @... - ellipsis (other params)
 * 
 * Return: the sum
 */

int sum_them_all(const unsigned int n, ...)
{
  unsigned int i;
  va_list ag;
  unsigned int sum = 0;

  va_start(ag, n);

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    sum += va_arg(ag, int);  
  }

  va_end(ag);
  return (sum);
}```
````

Comment: Put `sum_them_all` first in the file.

Comment: That's what the standard requires. You **must** make a prototype visible at the call site.

Comment: When you first call `sum_them_all`, it assumes it is a function taking *fixed* arguments, and returning `int`.  That means the later definition of the function could specify almost any arguments it wanted to — *as long as they are fixed*.  But they can't be variable.  So you need to, at least, declare function `sum_them_all` before you call it — but of course that's good practice anyway.  Either put the line `int sum_them_all(unsigned int, ...);` at the top of the file, or move the definition of the function there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in one of two ways.  First, you could move the `main` function after your `sum_them_all` function so that the compiler knows how to utilize this function.  Second, you could add a function prototype at the beginning of your code before the function is called.

```
int sum_them_all(const unsigned int, ...);
```

Either way should resolve your issue.

Comment: Can't imagine I forgot that. I really appreciate.